# Function to save image's src doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below displays images and make one of them selected (with blue borders) if I click on it. It also stores the src of the selected one in a variable (`src1`), but this last point doesn't work. Where's my mistake? Thank you guys!

```
var src1 = "";
var img = new Array();
img[0] = new Image();
img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
img[1] = new Image();
img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
img[2] = new Image();
img[2].src = "../images/poggiatesta3.jpg";
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    var imagetag = document.createElement("img");
    var onclick = document.createAttribute("onclick");
    onclick.value = "myfun(" + i + ")";

    var sorc = document.createAttribute("src");
    sorc.value = img[i].src;

    var id = document.createAttribute("id");
    id.value = "my_image" + i;

    var clas = document.createAttribute("class");
    clas.value = "my_image_clas";

    imagetag.setAttributeNode(clas);
    imagetag.setAttributeNode(onclick);
    imagetag.setAttributeNode(sorc);
    imagetag.setAttributeNode(id);
    document.body.appendChild(imagetag);
}
function myfun(i) {
    src1 = document.getElementById('my_image' + i).src;

}
var _last = null;
function select(element) {
    element.onclick = function () {
        element.classList.toggle('selected');
        if (_last) _last.classList.remove("selected");
        _last = element.classList.contains("selected") ? element : null;
    }
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_image_clas')).forEach(select);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var src1 = "";
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = new Image();
    img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
    img[1] = new Image();
    img[1].src =  "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
    img[2] = new Image();
    img[2].src =  "../images/poggiatesta3.jpg";


 for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    var imagetag = document.createElement("img");


    var sorc = document.createAttribute("src");
    sorc.value = img[i].src;

    var id = document.createAttribute("id");
    id.value = "my_image" + i;

    var clas = document.createAttribute("class");
    clas.value = "my_image_clas";

    imagetag.setAttributeNode(clas);
    imagetag.setAttributeNode(sorc);
    imagetag.setAttributeNode(id);
    document.body.appendChild(imagetag);

}

var _last = null;
function select(element) {
    element.onclick = function () {
        element.classList.toggle('selected');
        if (_last) _last.classList.remove("selected");
        _last = element.classList.contains("selected") ? element : null;
        src1 = _last.src;
    }
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_image_clas')).forEach(select);
```

Answer (score 2):

You use a wrong way to add the event of your element. Your event is not triggered.

Use this way instead :

```
var imagetag = document.createElement("img");
imagetag.onclick = function () {
    myfun(i);
};
```

Comment: Should i put this code just above the for cycle? Because it doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you describe your error ? Did you enter into the function `myfun`? If yes,  what is the value of `i` ?